# change and manipulate lines in a file using awk

Tags: text-processing, awk, bioinformatics

I have a file with the following format

```
>M03117:162:000000000-ATLWF:1:1114:22047:12565:307
TCCGAAAGT-ACAACGTGT
>M03117:162:000000000-ATLWF:1:2104:9367:8166:307
TTCGAAAGTT-GGTGAGGTGTGGG
>M03117:162:000000000-ATLWF:1:1119:11492:8271:307
TCCGAAAGTTCTCCGA-CTTGGCTTCCTAG
>M03117:162:000000000-ATLWF:1:2111:19039:8200:307
GACGAAAGTTCACCGATA-GAGGTAGAAGGTGCAGTGGGGA
```

I would like to manipulate and change the lines so that the 2nd line is split into two separated by "-" to a new line and the name before identified by ">" copied in the new line and renamed by _2 at the end of the name, as follows;

```
>M03117:162:000000000-ATLWF:1:1114:22047:12565:307
TCCGAAAGT
>M03117:162:000000000-ATLWF:1:1114:22047:12565:307_2
ACAACGTGT
>M03117:162:000000000-ATLWF:1:2104:9367:8166:307
TTCGAAAGTT
>M03117:162:000000000-ATLWF:1:2104:9367:8166:307_2
GGTGAGGTGTGGG
>M03117:162:000000000-ATLWF:1:1119:11492:8271:307
TCCGAAAGTTCTCCGA
>M03117:162:000000000-ATLWF:1:1119:11492:8271:307_2
CTTGGCTTCCTAG
>M03117:162:000000000-ATLWF:1:2111:19039:8200:307
GACGAAAGTTCACCGATA
>M03117:162:000000000-ATLWF:1:2111:19039:8200:307_2
GAGGTAGAAGGTGCAGTGGGGA
```

I know this could be done by awk but I can't come up with anything.

Comment: Please, could you post your actual efforts?

Comment: you can save lines starting with `>` into a variable, use `-` as field separator, and print as per requirements...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perl to the rescue

```
perl -laF/-/ -ne '
    if (/^>/) { print; $header = "$_\_2"; }
    else { print join "\n", $F[0], $header, $F[1] }
' -- input-file
```

- `-n` reads the input line by line
- `-l` removes newlines from input and adds them to `print` statements
- `-aF/-/` splits the input on `-`

When reading a header line, it outputs it and stores the header for later use. When processing a sequence, it prints the first part, the stored header, and the second part.

Comment: This works. thanks a lot choroba but i must admit am not as good with perl

Answer (score 2):

Since you specifically asked about "using awk"

```
awk -F- '
  /^>/ {hdr=$0; next} 
  {print hdr ORS $1; for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) print hdr"_"i ORS $i}
' file
```

Comment: You have answered the question. Good job.

Comment: But you don't need a loop. This also works: `awk -F- '/^>/{hdr=$0; next}{print hdr ORS $1; i=2; print hdr"_"i ORS $i}' file`

Answer (score 2):

Capture lines which start with `>` in `header` and go to `next` input record for further processing.
Than print a line with the `header` a `\n` and column 1 of the *new* input record.
Than repeat this for the second column and add 2 to your header.

```
$ awk -F- '/^>/{header=$0; next}{print header ORS $1; print header"_2" ORS $2}' file
>M03117:162:000000000-ATLWF:1:1114:22047:12565:307
TCCGAAAGT
>M03117:162:000000000-ATLWF:1:1114:22047:12565:307_2
ACAACGTGT
>M03117:162:000000000-ATLWF:1:2104:9367:8166:307
TTCGAAAGTT
>M03117:162:000000000-ATLWF:1:2104:9367:8166:307_2
GGTGAGGTGTGGG
>M03117:162:000000000-ATLWF:1:1119:11492:8271:307
TCCGAAAGTTCTCCGA
>M03117:162:000000000-ATLWF:1:1119:11492:8271:307_2
CTTGGCTTCCTAG
>M03117:162:000000000-ATLWF:1:2111:19039:8200:307
GACGAAAGTTCACCGATA
>M03117:162:000000000-ATLWF:1:2111:19039:8200:307_2
GAGGTAGAAGGTGCAGTGGGGA
```

Answer (score 1):

If you like to help yourself, but don't want to learn programming, you can do stuff like this with `sed`. You simply always read the next line with `N`, separate the double-line into it's parts surrounded by `()` and combine those part referred to as `\1` for the first and so on as needed:

```
sed -E 'N;s/(.*)(\n)(.*)-(.*)/\1\2\3\2\1_2\2\4/' file
```

You can also do it without extended regular expressions (no option `-E`), but you may get lost in backslashes:

```
sed 'N;s/\(.*\)\(\n\)\(.*\)-\(.*\)/\1\2\3\2\1_2\2\4/' file
```

Same result, achieved by hold buffer usage, but not so obvious if you are new to `sed`:

```
sed 'h;n;y/-/\n/;P;s/.*\n//;x;s/$/_2/;G' file
```

Comment: Now I finally expanded GNU `sed` a tiny bit: `\h` in the replacement string inserts the hold space, a function I was missing many times. The script becomes very compact and readable then: `sed 'h;n;s/-/\n\h_2\n/' file`